# change base url in local copy in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I want to copy my website (Orchard 1.7.2.0) to localhost, to test some things before I do that on the live site.

Ik copied the database and de web directory and configured iis. In the orchards database I changed the base url in the Settings_SiteSettings2PartRecord table. I also changed the database connection in settings.txt

Now when I enter the new base url in the browser I get redirected to the original url. How can I prevent this? I can't find any other reference to the original url.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Hard to say with so little information. Looks like a badly configured IIS, but could be something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what went wrong.

There was a rewrite in the database to the originial url (for removing www in the url). I removed that and now it works.